React Native Build Issue with Android SDK Build Tools Version Warning After Update
I'm developing a React Native app and I recently encountered an issue after updating Android Studio. I was prompted to update, and after doing so, I ran 'Sync Project' which resulted in the following warning:
"The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (33.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (33.0.1) for Android Gradle Plugin 8.1.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 33.0.1 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools."
However, my build.gradle file is set up as follows:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}


Despite the warning suggesting an issue with "buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'", my configuration explicitly specifies buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0". I'm unsure what's causing this mismatch or how to resolve the warning. Could anyone help clarify what might be going wrong here or how to correctly address this issue?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Additionally, my Gradle version is 8.7.

Did you get any solution yet? since I am also facing the same issue.

You have to take a look at the logs. In my case, the problem was with the react-native-reanimated library.
Android gradle plugin: 8.5.0
Gradle: 8.8
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (33.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (34.0.0) for Android Gradle Plugin 8.5.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 34.0.0 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'" from your build.gradle...

With that information, you may have a better understanding of which library is the culprit.

Did you solve this?
